# Updating multiple table in Sybase

Tags: sql, sql-update, sap-ase

Got a requirement to update certain fields of two tables (which got 60+ millions of rows) and I'm doing the UPDATE in a loop.

I'd like to update two tables in a single UPDATE (as its difficult to query/traverse twice these tables considering the volume of these tables).

I'm looking for something like these,

```
UPDATE TABLE_A, TABLE_B

SET TABLE_A.column1 = "new value",
SET TABLE_B.column2 = "different value"

FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b, TABLE_C c
WHERE <few conditions>
```

Sybase doesn't seems like this syntax though. Is there any alternatives anyone aware of ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is all tables from the same DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can define only one table in each UPDATE statement